# How to get multiple values from tail.select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tail.select

I'am working on kind of deprecated project which is using ***tail select***. I have to use option 'multiple'. Everything works smooth, I am able to select multiple options **BUT!** the value do not change at all. I always see the value of first selected item.

My input:
[image]

My options:

```
options.descriptions = true;
options.hideSelected = true;
options.hideDisabled = true;
options.multiLimit = 10;
options.multiShowCount = false;
options.multiContainer = true;
```

I found there is a div, which accumulate the selected items and keeps it's values. But I'd need it to create array named `inputs` or something...

[image]

Is here some hero to help?
(I'd like to find out tail.select solution. I'm capable to catch form submit and map divs into array of inputs. **But I don't wanna do that!**.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have in your multiple select name array.

`<select name="departments[]" multiple>`

Then you got array of selected items in backend

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get these values with javascript, then you'll be experiencing the same issue that happens with normal select fields that have the multiple attribute. If that's the case, you could probably do...

```js
const mySelectField = document.querySelector('select[name="departments"]');
const getVal = () => {
    const options = mySelectField.querySelectorAll('option:checked');
    return Array.from(options, e => e.value);
};
```

But for sending your values in the request payload, you'll need to ensure you have the array syntax addded to your field name...

```html
<select name="departments[]" multiple>
    ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the values from Tail.Select from my router.get's request.query.
It came through as a string for a single selection and an array for multiple selection.

I tried suggestions earlier in this thread about naming my select with square brackets, but that messed up the URL and I decided not to do that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Tailselect is deprecated so far. I strongly recomend to use another js library for dropdowns.

Comment: Thank you for your answere @Julius. I will definitely consider that option

Comment: And be aware of select2 :D

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30257825)

Comment: It is not deprecated. It is actively maintained here - https://getbutterfly.com/tail-select/